# Saving measured data to text file

Tags: raspbian, python, measuring

Im using an ADC to measuring values and send them over a socket via the RP, yet I also want to save the values to my RP as I'm reading them. For some reason when I open the text file it only has the last value read. I don't know why I cant figure this out.

```
import socket
import struct
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_ADS1x15

#UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "169.254.65.163"#"169.254.168.20" #double check IP
UDP_PORT_NO = 6789

adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

GAIN = 1
i = 0

print('Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')
print('| {0:>6} | {1:>6} | {2:>6} | {3:>6} |'.format(*range(4)))
print('-' * 37)

while True:
    # Read all the ADC channel values in a list.
    values = []
    values.append(adc.read_adc(i, gain=GAIN))
    data = struct.pack("!d", values[i])
    clientSock.sendto(data, (UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))
    np.savetxt('RPA0data.txt', values, delimiter=',')
    print('| {0:>6} |'.format(*values))
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand this elliptic code, but a fundamental problem is that you are creating a NEW list with each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Milliways' comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90611/saving-measured-data-to-text-file#comment145163_90611) has pointed out: you are creating a new (and empty) list on each iteration of the `while True` loop. So `values = []` should be put outside that loop.

Assuming `np.savetext()` is from NumPy (which is not imported in the example) you will be re-writing the file with the full list of `values` (after fixing the above issue of course) for each iteration - which is likely not what you want. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27786868/3984613) one could append to a file using NumPy's `savetext()` but you will have to open the file yourself in append mode and hand the filehandle to `savetext()` instead of the filename. (Note that they propose to open the file in binary mode; I wonder why that is...)

```
f = open('asd.dat', 'ab')
np.savetxt(f, a)
f.close()
```

Of course outputting the values to a csv text file does not really require a special NumPy feature so one could just use native Python file handling to append a single new value to the file (example not using a list of values but just a single value):

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("{0}".format(value))
```